# Arabic Droid Naksh Font Display on Samsung S3 and S4

Tags: html, cordova, samsung-mobile

I'm observing a difference in Arabic Font using Samsung S3 and S4 
S4 is supporting while S3 not working on default browser
actually I am working Phone-gap APP ,take a look at below screen shots.

**Font Name:** Droid Arabic Naksh

### Samsung S4

[image]

### Samsung S3

[image]

Comment: Google also recommends these fonts for its products: http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess